# Creating hybrid properties automatically from SQLAlchemy Mixins

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy, I'd like to have a class that automatically creates hybrid properties to expose attributes from a specific child table. Consider this structure:

```
class Address(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    street = Column(String)
    number = Column(Integer)
    valid_from = Column(DateTime)
    valid_to = Column(DateTime)
    person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'))
    person = relationship('Person', backref=backref('addresses', lazy='dynamic')

class Person(db.Model, HybridPropertyGeneratorMixin):

    data_class = Address

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    @property
    def current_address(self):
        return self.addresses.order_by(desc(Address.valid_from))[0]

    @hybrid_property
    def city(cls):
        return self.current_address.city

    @city.expression
    def city(cls):
        return select([Address.name]). \
        where(cls.id==Address.person_id). \
        where(Address.valid_to == None).as_scalar()
```

What I'm trying to do is define a mixin that would automatically look at the attributes of data_class and generate hybrid attributes and expressions from the data_class's attributes. For example, I want to automatically define the hybrid property and expression for city, state, street, etc.

**UPDATE**
Wasn't clear enough in what I originally wanted to do. See above for an update as to why I want to automatically generate hybrid properties and expressions.

Comment: This is not a quick answer, but I think that combining the two recipes below should give you an idea about one way you can achieve this goal: [`QuickHybrid`](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/QuickHybrid) and [`RelationshipToLatest`](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/RelationshipToLatest)

Answer (score 1):

You can override the special method [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) to get the attribute from `current_address` if it's not an attribute of `person`.

```
class Person(db.Model):
    # ...

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.current_address, item)
```